# Perform lots of checks but still get error when inserting data into Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am using both Unity and Visual Studio to manage a website that uses Unity and C#.

I have a world map that loads fine, but displays this error in the browser console:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: key

So I loaded up Unity, to see if I could find any errors and saw one for a file called *MapDisplay.cs*.

Looking at the error, I assume it has something to do with a dictionary object.

In that code file, there is indeed one dictionary object.

However, it looks like the code is checking for anything that may be null.

So I am not sure how much more I can check?

Is there a more efficient way to check for null values in a dictionary so that the error doesn't display?

Here is the code for the dictionary object:

```cs
public Dictionary<string, MapController> MapDictionary;
MapController mapController = CreateMapController(mapData);

if (mapController != null)
{
    if (mapController.MapId != null || mapController.MapId != "")
    {
        string mapControllerId = mapController.MapId;

        if (!MapDictionary.ContainsKey(mapControllerId))
        {
            MapDictionary.Add(mapControllerId, mapController);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mapController.MapId)`. `mapController.MapId != null || mapController.MapId != ""` with value `null`, the if condition is true.

Comment: This condition `if (mapController.MapId != null || mapController.MapId != "")` will always evaluate to `true`, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: You want && (AND) NOT || (OR). There is the 
`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mapController.MapId)` method that already does that.

Comment: upping @Ralf .. note though that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` covers more edge cases like e.g. only space and tab characters .. unlikely that in this case this matters but it is not exactly the same as checking for `null` or `""` ;) .. in this use case it is most probably what you want to go with since as said .. it covers even more edge cases

Comment: @derHugo correct. You pressumably missed to mentioned `string.IsNullOrEmpty` as the exact corresponding method to his check ;)

Comment: @Ralf I think I understand, so I can replace this `if (mapController.MapId != null || mapController.MapId != "")` with this `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mapController.MapId))` ?

Comment: @derHugo thanks, so replacing all of my checks for null, with this `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mapController.MapId)) {...}` will cover all the bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the `if` condition issue discussed in the comments.

You can use (`?.`) optional chaining to deal that the `mapController` is possibly `null`.

With .NET Core, you can use [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryAdd(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-6.0).

```cs
string mapControllerId = mapController?.MapId;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mapControllerId))
{
    MapDictionary.TryAdd(mapControllerId, mapController);
}
```

If not, you can write a Dictionary extension method for `TryAdd` to deal with.

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static bool TryAdd<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue @value)
    {
        try
        {
            dict.Add(key, @value);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, does the code you wrote, `string mapControllerId = mapController?.MapId ?? "";` mean that if either mapController or mapController.MapId are empty or null, then mapControllerId will be a string like "" ?

Comment: Actually `mapController?. MapId` is enough, don't need the nullish operator. As the next if statement will check null or empty string. The optional chaining is aim to safe access the nested properties. When the value is found null, then it won't continue for accessing nested properties.